# PHP Web Crawler doesn't crawl .php files

Tags: php, regex, web-crawler

This is the simple webcrawler I was trying to build

```
<?php

    $to_crawl = "http://samplewebsite.com/about.php";

    function get_links($url)
    {
        $input = @file_get_contents($url);
        $regexp = " <a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a> ";
        preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches);

        $l = $matches[2];

        foreach ($l as $link) {
            echo $link."</br>";
        }
    }


    get_links($to_crawl);


?>
```

When I try to run the script with the $to_crawl variable set to a url ending with a file name, e.g. "facebook.com/about", it works, but for some reason, it just echo's nothing when the link is ending with a '.php' filename. Can someone please help?

Comment: can you get the result of that link in a browser?

Comment: Yes it works fine, and I put it through my python written web crawler and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Try `$regexp = "\\s*<a\\s+[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>\\s*";`. Also, do you consider using DOMDocument? You seem to just collect `<a>` tag href URLs with the inner texts. Right?

Comment: Correct, I have no idea what a DOMDocument is sorry, would it be easier? And thank you, your edit of my $regexp worked :)

Comment: @SamirChahine: I posted an answer with an example of how you can leverage DOMDocument + DOMXPath, which I consider to be the best tool combination to scrape any info from a Web page. Especially if you need just text from specific nodes/attributes. Regex is too unsafe with arbitrary HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all links and their inner texts, you can use `DOMDocument` like this:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($input);                    // Your input (HTML code)

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xp->query('//a[@href]');          // XPath to get only <a> tags with a href attribute

$result = array();
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $result[] = array($link->getAttribute("href"), $link->nodeValue);
}
print_r($result);
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/7ZLnoM)